# How do I increase the spacing before and after the empheq environment (with tcolorbox)?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, tcolorbox, boxes, empheq

I want to ask a question on how to properly increase the spacing before and after the boxes set inside an empheq environment. Here's my MWE that I compiled using LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[DIV=15]
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} % Colored boxes
\usepackage{empheq} % Emphasize equations

\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,capture=hbox,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt}}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
\chapter{Basic Properties of Numbers}
\section{Laws of Inequalities}
\subsection{Absolute Value and the Triangle Inequality}

The fact that \(-a > 0\) if \(a < 0\) is the basis of a concept which will play an extremely important role in this book. For any number \(a\), we define the \textbf{absolute value} \(\abs{a}\) of \(a\) as follows:
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
    \abs{a} =
    \begin{cases*}
        \phantom{-}a, & if \(a\geq 0\) \\
        -a, & if \(a\leq 0\). 
    \end{cases*} 
\end{empheq}
Note that \(\abs{a}\) is always positive, except when \(a = 0\). For example, we have \(\abs{-3} = 3\), \(\abs{7} = 7\), \(\abs{1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}} = 1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}\), and \(\abs{1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{10}} = \sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2} - 1\). In general, the most straigtforward approach to any problem involving absolute values requires treating several cases separately, since absolute values are defined by cases to begin with. This approach may be used to prove the following very important fact about absolute values.
\end{document}
```

[image: First MWE]

I've tried using the options `before skip` and `after skip` provided by the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[DIV=15]
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} % Colored boxes
\usepackage{empheq} % Emphasize equations

\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,boxrule=1pt,capture=hbox,arc=0mm,boxsep=0pt,before skip=2.5em, after skip=2.5em}}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
\chapter{Basic Properties of Numbers}
\section{Laws of Inequalities}
\subsection{Absolute Value and the Triangle Inequality}

The fact that \(-a > 0\) if \(a < 0\) is the basis of a concept which will play an extremely important role in this book. For any number \(a\), we define the \textbf{absolute value} \(\abs{a}\) of \(a\) as follows:
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
    \abs{a} =
    \begin{cases*}
        \phantom{-}a, & if \(a\geq 0\) \\
        -a, & if \(a\leq 0\). 
    \end{cases*} 
\end{empheq}
Note that \(\abs{a}\) is always positive, except when \(a = 0\). For example, we have \(\abs{-3} = 3\), \(\abs{7} = 7\), \(\abs{1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}} = 1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}\), and \(\abs{1 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{10}} = \sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2} - 1\). In general, the most straigtforward approach to any problem involving absolute values requires treating several cases separately, since absolute values are defined by cases to begin with. This approach may be used to prove the following very important fact about absolute values.
\end{document}
```

[image: Second MWE]

But it seems to not work inside the `empheq` environment. Is there any way I can increase the spacing before and after an `empheq` environment? (preferably without using `\vspace` if possible.) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whith little changes:

```
\vskip .5cm % <<<--- added
 \begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
    \abs{a} =
    \begin{cases*}
        \phantom{-}a, & if \(a\geq 0\) \\
        -a, & if \(a\leq 0\). 
    \end{cases*} 
\end{empheq}
\vskip .5cm %<<<--- added
```

you have this result:

[image]

Comment: This does seem to work without returning any warnings but do you know how to vertically center the box in between paragraphs after adding in the `vskip`s? The spacing before the box seems to be bigger than the one after it even though the `vskip` values are the same. Thank you.

Comment: This is true because the line above is not complete! You ave to adjust this manually and  change the first .5 cm in .3cm.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand. Could you elaborate a little further, please?

Comment: You have a third of line complete before the formula. So also without \vskip you have more free space above formula than after the formula. So you can balance this with:
\vskip .3cm
...
\vskip .5 cm